# Convert Oracle query to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am facing an issue while converting a query from Oracle to snowflake. Could you please help out.

Sample Oracle query:
replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR( col_name,'(.*?)([[:space:]]>>[[:space:]]|$)', 1,1 ) , ' >> ','') as test

Comment: can you post an example input and an expected output. because `'abc >> ' as con_name` seems to be working for me, so I am not sure what you have that you think should work but is not working..

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you please share your sample oracle input.

Comment: you want first field ? `select REGEXP_SUBSTR('test1 >> test2 >> test3' , '[^>>]+' ,1) as val;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Snowflake behaves different when processing (.*?) part of your regular expression. As a workaround, you may use [^>]* or \w+ instead of (.*?):

```
SELECT
replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'test1 >> test2 >> test3','([^>]*)([[:space:]]>>[[:space:]]|$)', 1,1 ) , ' >> ','') as test;

SELECT
replace(REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'test1 >> test2 >> test3','\\w+([[:space:]]>>[[:space:]]|$)', 1,1) , ' >> ','') as test;
```

These should give the same result ("test1") with Oracle's REGEXP_SUBSTR.

Comment: Thanks buddy, this is working as per my expectation